# Tor browser 32-bit version VS 64-bit

Tags: tor-browser-bundle

Is TorBrowser 32-bit version less secure than 64-bit? If so, what vulnerabilities can be exploited?

Answer (score 1):

It is not less secure. However if you are using it on a 32-bit version of Windows like XP or Windows 7 that is no longer being patched, then you are open to all Windows exploits since that time.